# asp.net - Is there a ajax end event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, treeview

In my asp.net page, I am using a treeview, and there is a asp button control that when clicked will expand every node in the tree.

The button is in an update panel so it uses ajax. The problem is in the ajax call, whatever changes I do to the tree, will not work.

I know that treeview can't be used in update panels, so is there a way to refresh the treeview?

Or maybe is there an ajax end event or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are exist several event which is raised when partial postback to server is completed.

You can handle load event of the Sys.Application object or pageLoaded event of the page request manager. Handling of the pageLoaded event is preferable because it is raised after html was updated on behalf of the partial request (content of the update panel).

Here is example of the existing events which you can handle:

```
var requestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

requestManager.add_beginRequest(function () { Sys.Debug.trace('Begin Request event was raised.'); });
requestManager.add_endRequest(function () { Sys.Debug.trace('End Request event was raised.'); });
requestManager.add_initializeRequest(function () { Sys.Debug.trace('Initialize Request event was raised.'); });
requestManager.add_pageLoaded(function () { Sys.Debug.trace('Page Loaded event was raised.'); });
requestManager.add_pageLoading(function () { Sys.Debug.trace('Page Loading event was raised.'); });

Sys.Application.add_load(function () { Sys.Debug.trace('Application load event was raised.'); });
```

More information about this events can be found using the following articles:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397566%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310856%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: can I use this to refresh a treeview? (without causing a postback to refresh the page)

Comment: I don't have experience using tree view control in ASP.NET. But if you can update this control without partial postback (for example using ajax request + then updating html using javascript) then you can do this without handling these events.